# How to select one value to be displayed in SPSS to be displayed as chart

Tags: charts, statistics, spss

I have two variables Career and Internet usage, there are two career options but I only want to select one value.

When I generate the pie chart in the output window I get and overview of internet usage but it includes both of the careers I only want a specific career to be shown in the pie chart e.g

How do people from System engineering use the internet as opposed to how does everyone use the internet

I don't know if this is clear, but if it is how would I do this in SPSS? is there some sort of filter_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one chart you can use `TEMPORARY` followed by a `SELECT IF`. If the the chart command follows directly after it will only plot that subset.

```
DATA LIST FREE / Career Internet.
BEGIN DATA
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 2
END DATA.
VALUE LABELS Internet 
  1 '2-4 Hours a Day' 
  2 '5-7 Hours a Day' 
  3 'Over 7 Hours a Day'.

TEMPORARY.
SELECT IF Career = 2.
GRAPH
  /PIE=COUNT BY Internet.
```

[image]

If you have multiple charts see the `FILTER` command.